# Login screen check usernames and passwords from a file

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter

I am a python/tkinter beginner. I am currently working on a school project to create a login screen. If the username and password exists in the data.dat file the main menu screen will open, otherwise an error message will appear. So far i can only get the system to recognize the first username and password in the first line of the data.dat file. If i try to enter any other username and password combination that exists my program crashes without any error messages prompting me of the fault. I presume it is a logical error but i just cant see it. Appreciate any help...

```py
def LoginScreen():
    
    def login():
        username=usname.get()
        passwd=password.get()
        flag=False

        if username.strip() == "" and passwd.strip() == "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Blank username and password")
        elif passwd.strip() == "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Blank password")
        elif username.strip()== "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Blank username")
        else:

            LoginFile=open("data.dat","r")

            for line in LoginFile:
                while flag ==False:
                    if username and passwd in line:
                        messagebox.showinfo("Authenticated","Correct username and password" )
                        flag=True
                    else:
                        flag =False
                if flag == False:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Inorrect username and password")
            loginwindow.destroy()
            MainMenu()
                                         

        
    loginwindow=Tk()
    loginwindow.title("Log In Screen")
    loginwindow.geometry("200x200")
    lbluname=Label(loginwindow, text="Username")
    usname=Entry(loginwindow)
    lblpass=Label(loginwindow, text="Password")
    password=Entry(loginwindow)

    lbluname.pack()
    usname.pack()
    lblpass.pack()
    password.pack()

    btn=Button(loginwindow,text="Log In",command=login).pack()
```

Comment: please format your question and place `code` in code blocks.

Comment: `if username and passwd in line:` should probably be something like `if username in line and passwd in line:`. You have to have each condition be a complete statement. That said we would need to see an example of your dat file format to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Unfortunately it is still not working. not sure if it’s something to do with the loop structure. My .dat file just has each username and password on the same line e.g admin cloud453 then the next username password on the next line

Answer (score 0):

You should use a context manager like "with open()" when you want to read a file so that it closes without an explicit call. However, You should be able to just open and check the file for the username and password.  I tested this using pathlib with a .dat file and it works fine.  See if this can help you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from pathlib import Path


def login_verify():
    username = admin_username_verify.get()# get info from field
    password = admin_password_verify.get()# get info from field
    username_entry.delete("0", tk.END) # delete info after button press
    password_entry.delete("0", tk.END)# delete info after button press
    file = "data.dat"  # file name
    nothing = "" # use to check empty field

    if username != nothing and password != nothing: # check if the fields are empty
        if username in Path(file).read_text() and password in Path(file).read_text(): #use pathlib to open and check file contents
            print("Access Granted")
        else:
            print("Incorrect Username/Password combination")
    else:
        print("Invalid Credentials")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.title("Administrator Login")


admin_username_verify = tk.StringVar()
admin_password_verify = tk.StringVar()

login_label = tk.Label(root, text="Please enter details below to login", font="Times 12 bold")
login_label.pack()
user_name_label = tk.Label(root, text="Username *", font="Times 10 bold")
user_name_label.pack(pady=2)
username_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=admin_username_verify, font="Times 12")
username_entry.pack()
password_label = tk.Label(root, text="Password *", font="Times 10 bold")
password_label.pack()
password_entry = tk.Entry(root, text=admin_password_verify, show="*", font="Times 12")
password_entry.pack()
login_button = tk.Button(root, text="Login", bg="blue", fg="white", width=10,
                         command= login_verify)
login_button.pack(pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Works really well.